# How to get the index of an element in an 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
int[][] triangle = {  
                              {75},
                             {87,64}, //If index is 0, then start from j = 0 in 3rd row (24, 56, 88)
                               {24, 56, 88}, // if index is 2 then start from j = 2 in 4th row (43, 45, 67, 76),  and compare 67 and 76, and find the max
                               {43, 45, 67, 76}
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        int  x = triangle[i][j];
         int y = triangle[i][j + 1];
            int max = Math.max(x, y);
      if (someCondition) {
          //getTheIndexOFMaxVariable (Here If I am looking for 64 then it should give me 1 as an index)
       }
    }
 }
```

- My question is if I am looking for element `64` then it should give me index as an `1` instead of `[1][1]`

Is there any way I can get the index of an array like `1` instead of `[1][1]`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why use a kludge, an asymmetric array, when a much better solution exists -- to create and use a 3 int Triangle class?

Comment: In that case, when `someCondition` is met, just use the j variable. Adding a "return j" (if this is in its own method) should do the trick.

Comment: @ahjohnston25 I am checking the maximum of two values in the array, So I can't do that cuz I am comparing the max value and then want to get the index, and It's already checking for like (j+ 1), So that's not possible.

Comment: Your question is not explaining your use case. It would be great if you also provide the use case then we can help you with some more ideas.

Comment: Even a single dimensional array, one that holds 3 items, is better than what you're using.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The question I am trying to solve need an 2D array, So that's why I am using it.

Comment: @Hemlata you'd get better answers if you tell us **what** you're trying to solve. Perhaps there's a more efficient way that you're not thinking of.

Comment: @Leozeo I edited it. Can you please have a look.

Comment: This question has [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By converting your 2D Array `int[][]` to `List<List<Integer>>`, you can take advantage of `indexOf` to find the index of your `max`:

```
List<List<Integer>> triangle = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    triangle.add(Arrays.asList(75));
    triangle.add(Arrays.asList(95, 64));

    for (List<Integer> row : triangle) {
        // you can also ask for row.indexOf(max);
        System.out.println("At row: " + triangle.indexOf(row) + " is: " + row.indexOf(64));         
    }
```

Comment: How can I loop through it?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question, do you meant for loop through `row` list? If yes, of course you can:
`for (List<Integer> row : triangle) {
   for (Integer nr : row) {
      // some code
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken but wouldn't the index be the `j` variable?

Since you are looping over the array with first loop, `i` will contain the index of current array (relative to the parent array).

But second loop iterates over the child arrays, so the index of your element will be the `j`.

```
int[][] triangle = {  
            {75},
            {95,64}
  };

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      // notice we use j variable to access the item, since it contains the index for current
      int item = array[i][j];

      if (item == 64) {
          // your code
       }
    }
 }
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the update, I'd recommend to throw away the Math.max function because that makes you lose the track of the index. Since you only have 2 elements to compare, a simple if statement would do.

```
int x = triangle[i][j];
int y = triangle[i][j + 1];
int max = 0;
int indexOfMax = 0;

// using >= just in case if both numbers are equal
if (x >= y) {
    max = x;
    indexOfMax = j;
} else {
    max = y;
    indexOfMax = j + 1;
}

if (someCondition) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I edited my code. Can you please have a look at it again?

Comment: @Hemlata take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: No in my array there are more than 2 elements.

Comment: That was just an example. It can have even have 100 or 1000.

Comment: Wait, I know the array might have more than 2 elements, but aren't you comparing just the j and j + 1 elements?

Comment: @Hemlata: you will likely get better answers if you would explain your problem better, as has been asked multiple times in the comments to your original question.

Comment: No, I am comparing more than j and j++

Comment: Can you tell us more? How many elements are you comparing to each other, and how many total elements are in the array? We need to know in order to help you with your solution

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: Can you please have a look?