# How to get the index of a multidimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to right a movement system for a Text-based rpg, I know that sound stupid but I want to try. I am using a 4 by 4 array to represent a 4 by 4 grid. The players position on the grid will be based on the index of the array.

Example:

`int[][] mapGrid = new int[4][4]`

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][P][]
[][][][]
```

So the player would be on grid square 2,2 corresponding to the index: mapGrid[2][2].

But every time I try find the index from mapGrid using:

```
System.out.println(ArrayUtils.indexOf(mapGrid,2)); //searching array for the value of 2 and return index
```

It only returns: -1 in the console. I will paste the full code here:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
public class MovementProto
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[][] mapGrid = {
                      {1,2,3,4},
                      {5,6,7,8},
                      {9,10,11,12},
                      {13,14,15,16}
                  };

        System.out.println(ArrayUtils.indexOf(mapGrid,2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought it could be because of the ArrayUtils class but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Be careful with your code formatting. The triple backticks must be on their own lines. I fixed this case for you.

Comment: Hint: `int[][]` is same as `(int[])[]`. So what do you think `indexOf` work on and look for?

Comment: That is interesting but I am not sure if I am getting the right thing from it. My first thoughts when seeing your comment were that I made an array that was 4 by 4 so:
int[][] = new int[4][4],
since int[][] is the same as (int[])[] wouldn't indexOf be working on 4 and that is why it is returning -1?

Comment: just curious what kind of output you're expecting from your example? `indexOf` returns single integer, but 2D array requires two integers to identify a position, so just by looking at the function's signature you can tell that it cannot be directly used in your scenario

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to get the output in some sort of `[x][x]` type of way but I wasn't sure how to write that. I am not sure if there is a better method to use other than `indexOf,`.

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375664/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-2d-array/42376016

Comment: 1. What is `ArrayUtils` class, do you use some library or is it your implementation? 2. If you search a 2D array, the utils method should return a pair of indexes and for your input data `scan(mapGrid, 2)` would result in `(0, 1)`

Comment: I saw that post when I first started looking for an answer and with the comments on my own post and going back over the one you sent it finally clicked for me, Thank you for everyone who helped answer the question :]